# Define the partial function where if n is the Godel number of a statement with proof in formal arithmetic, then $f(n) = 1$; otherwise $f(n) = 0$.

Tags: logic, partial-functions

I'm a bit confused with accurately defining partial functions. I'm trying to do the following exercise.

Define the partial function $f$ from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $ where if n is the Godel number of a statement with proof in formal arithmetic, then $f(n) = 1$; otherwise $f(n) = 0$.

This is what I have and I'm not sure if what I'm writing has anything to do with partial functions as I'm getting partial functions confused with partial recursiveness and being Turing computable:

$$f(n) = \begin{cases} 1, &\text{if n is the Godel number of a statement with proof in formal arithmetic} \\
0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Frankly speaking, it is not very clear... Do you have an initial set of functions/predicates to be used, like e.g. [$\text {Prf}_F (x, n)$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#AriForLan) ?

Comment: I think partial recursive functions contain the initial functions (zero, successor, projection), closed under composition, primitive recursion and minimisation.

Comment: We can use anything built on that, and we can use things like $\text{Prf}_F(x,n)$

Comment: In terms of formal arithmetic, can use anything built on 0, successor, binary functions $=$ and $\cdot$, identity ($=$), variables, and symbols (for all, there exists, and, or, implies, etc.)